# SQL Server Get Updated Column Value

Tags: sql-server

I have a col1 in my table with initial value of 0 with one row, I want to get updated value of col1.

My update query is :

```
Update table set col1 = col1 + 1
```

I can get last update by put output like :

```
Update table set col1 = col1 + 1 OUTPUT inserted.col1
```

But I am not sure that output value is related same query or last updated by other query at same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value returned is the value of this update statement.  It will not reflect updates made by other users.

**EDIT:**

You can also store the value in a variable without an `OUTPUT` clause (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx):

```
Update table set @col1 = col1 = col1 + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I have another question how can I  insert into output value like this Insert into table2 (Col1)values(Update table set col1 = col1 + 1 OUTPUT inserted.col1)?

Comment: @ShaahinRoshan That's already specified in [the doc for the OUTPUT clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).  `OUTPUT <fieldlist> INTO output_table ( column_list )`.

Comment: @BaconBits : Thanks for your reply but I don't want into a table I want store result as value or set to a variable

Comment: @ShaahinRoshan, I edited my answer to who how to set a variable to the updated value without an `OUTPUT` clause.